# What is the time complexity of String.toCharArray(), O(n) or O(1)

Tags: java, string

Suppose you want to convert a String of length n to a character array of length n.

```
char [] chArray = someString.toCharArray();
```

What is the computation complexity?O(n) or O(1) ( n: length of someString)

I am under the impression that all it does is to allocate memory of size n*sizeof(char) and make a copy of that string to that location. So copying n cells of memory takes  O(n) time. Is it ?

or it could be O(1), ( simple pointer relocation or as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476692/time-complexity-of-array-manipulation))?

Comment: You could take a look at the source code...or read the javadoc.

Comment: `System.arrayCopy()` works on O(N)

Comment: @JigarJoshi why not posted as an answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165594/time-complexity-of-system-arraycopy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is linear time.

Think of it as copying single char and putting it into an array. It depends on number of elements so it's O(n).

Comment: Although the copy for n=0 through n=512 might be the same duration and might go up in increments of some larger constant value.

Comment: That means a low constant factor, not a change in the actual asymptotics.

Answer (score 1):

It's linear time; it does the copy, and copies take linear time.  (The constant factor might be quite low, but it's still linear overall.)